# WordPress Footer Menu - Format On Single Line

Tags: css, wordpress

I was able to create a second menu for the WordPress Twenty Ten theme and add it to the footer of my child theme. The code I modified in the child theme footer is as follows:

```
<div id="site-info">
<!-- EDIT -->
Copyright (c) 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved.
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu' ) ); ?>
<!-- EDIT -->
</div><!-- #site-info -->
```

The footer menu works but the formatting is not correct. The current formatting is as follows:

```
Copyright (c) 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved.
- Privacy Policy
- Terms & Conditions
```

I want the formatting so everything stays on a single line with the "|" symbol separating Privacy Policy and Terms & Conditions. I also want to loose the bullets (not sure where they came from?). Like so:

```
Copyright (c) 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved. Privacy Policy | Terms & Conditions
```

I assume it is a CSS issue but I'm unsure?

Footer section as rendered by the browser:

```
    <div id="footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div id="colophon">
            <div id="site-info">
                <!-- EDIT -->
                Copyright &copy; 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved.
                <div class="menu-footer-container">
                <ul id="menu-footer" class="menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-41 current_page_item menu-item-48">
                        <a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=41">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49">
                        <a href="http://www.kb8b.com/?page_id=39">Terms & Conditions</a>
                    </li>
</ul></div>                <!-- EDIT -->
            </div><!-- #site-info -->

            <div id="site-generator">
                <!-- EDIT -->
                <!-- EDIT -->
            </div><!-- #site-generator -->

        </div><!-- #colophon -->
    </div><!-- #footer -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->
```

Comment: CAn you paste in the HTML as it's rendered in the browser?

Comment: Added the footer section as rendered by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In your `style.css` in the child theme directory, add in the lines:

```
ul#menu-footer li
{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
```

You'll also have to set a width to the `<ul>` itself and fiddle about with its positioning.

Comment: They're still on a separate line, now they overlap, and the bullets are still there.

Comment: I added a rule you should use. And did you assign a width to the UL? And position it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

set `display` property as `inline` or `inline-block` for list elements.

Answer (score -1):

To show in single & remove bullet use code :-

```
 .menu-footer-container ul li
{
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: They're still on a separate line and now they overlap.

Comment: Now your content Copyright &copy; 2013 Acme Inc. All rights reserved. put in li without anchor tag.